# Does a site collections default language have any special significance?

Tags: sharepoint-online, language

Is there any special significance to having one language or the other as the default language when you create a site collection? This is on Sharepoint Online if that makes any difference.

Ie we´re a Swedish company but I prefer to administer in english. Does it matter if I create the site collection with english as the default language and add swedish as a supported language or create the site collection with swedish as the default language?

Comment: I agree with the answers below, and even the end users benefits from having the sites in English if they need to search for guidance or anything on the web. On the other hand, you can take a look about having multilingual sites. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-multilingual-features-53411469-53e3-4570-95e2-3651f166174f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our internal standards are to create everything in English, it just makes everything easier. If the need arises, additional language packs can be enabled on a web by web basis by site owners to include as many languages as needed. What this does is translate all the default SharePoint menu options and ribbon options to those users who have their preferred languages set in their profiles and where additional language packs are enabled.

So it really boils down to who has to administer the site and providing information on how to enable additional languages and how users can set preferred languages.

Answer (score 3):

as many times witnessed here, even tho the commands are in the same positions, translations may vary and it would be longer for you to troubleshoot problems since you will find very few pages explaining things in Swedish.

Secondly, Regional settings is one thing, but Locale (another control under regional settings) changes the way that time and date are displayed (30/12/2021 or 2021/12/30 or if time needs to have AM/PM or if you want the week of the calendar starting from sunday -us settings-).

I am not aware of what is the settings for Swedish but for a non-english European, to see am/pm and the week starting from sunday is not good.